# Update Azure ML realtime endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm generating a machine learning modell using Azure Auto ML. Is there a way to update my published real-time endpoint without deleting it first?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One approach with current integration between Azure ML and Azure DevOps is to setup a release pipeline in Azure DevOps which is triggered by the model registration in your Dev workspace model registry.
There is guidance and examples in this repo
https://github.com/Microsoft/MLOpsPython

And more general guidance for MLops at http://aka.ms/mlops

Please follow the below for retraining.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/ai/mlops-python#retraining-pipeline